# Clever way to do filtering and selection in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filtering

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do this operation in Python.  I would appreciate all suggestions.

I have an array of numeric data; some elements are NaN.  When I find a NaN, I want to select the 20 closest elements that are valid numeric values.  So, in the ideal case, the NaN datapoint is somewhere in the middle, and the 10 elements after it and the 10 elements before it are all valid numeric values.  In a trickier case there are only five elements in front of the NaN, and I have to select 15 elements after the NaN.  An even trickier case is there are only 5 elements before the NaN and there is also a NaN in the 15 elements after the original NaN so I must select 16 elements afterward (then filter out the NaN and resulting in my needed 15 elements).

I can do this by filtering out the NaN's from a dataframe and keeping a new and original index column but it is messy and I'm not an expert yet in pandas and numpy.  I have a feeling there is a clever way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Did you see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna) about that very topic?

Comment: @user2722968
The question is about selection not replacing NaN values.

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframe with expected output

Comment: What will you then do with those values? Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this example:

```
     col
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    5.0
9    NaN
10   6.0
11   NaN
12   7.0
13   8.0
14   9.0
15   NaN
16  10.0
```

You can use a combination of masks, [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

B = 2  # number of non-NA values before
A = 3  # after

# extract column as series
# ensure range index
s = df['col'].reset_index(drop=True)

# identify non-NA rows
m = s.notna()

# mask the indices of NAs and ffill
idx = s.index.to_series().where(m).ffill()

# craft a DataFrame from a sliding window view
tmp = pd.DataFrame(swv(s[m], A+B), index=idx[m].shift(-B+1)[:m.sum()-(A+B)+1])

# reindex with filled indices, set back original index, join
out = df.join(tmp.reindex(idx).set_axis(df.index).mask(m))
```

Output:

```
     col    0    1    2    3    4
0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4    NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
5    NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
6    3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7    4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8    5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9    NaN  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
10   6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11   NaN  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
12   7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13   8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14   9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16  10.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand, that for each row you want to look ahead 10 rows and use its value and in case it is NA you want to take the next non-NA value that follows this row and likewise forward.

Assuming you have a column `value` on which you want to operate, you can do this as follows:

```
shift_b = 10
shift_f = 15
ser_backward = df["value"].ffill().shift(shift_b)
ser_forward = df["value"].bfill().shift(-shift_f)
df["backward"] = ser_backward
df["forward"] = ser_forward
```

This will look ahead and back and will assume you apply the same gaps at the beginning and end of the dataset. If that is not the case you can apply `ffill` and `bfill` (see end of this posting).
The `shift` method does the main trick. It would be sufficient in case you do not require to skip NA values. Because you need to skip forward for lookforward, you need to propagate the non-NA-values for the lookforward backward to use the next non-NA value for each NA value. And do exactly the opposite in the lockback case.

**Test Data**

As an example, I use `shift_f=shift_b=3` (so locking backward and forward just 3 steps instead of 10) to visualize the effect with a smaller dataset. Let's assume we are interesting in applying the method on a column named `value`. We initially fill the column for some values with the value equal to the index of that row so it can be seen easily what happens.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import sample
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(20)))
non_null_indexes = [5, 19, 10, 4, 3, 2, 7, 13, 17]
df.loc[non_null_indexes, "value"] = non_null_indexes
```

**Result:**

|  | value | backward | forward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | nan | 3 |
| 1 | nan | nan | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | nan | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | nan | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | nan | 7 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 6 | nan | 3 | 10 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 | 10 |
| 8 | nan | 5 | 13 |
| 9 | nan | 5 | 13 |
| 10 | 10 | 7 | 13 |
| 11 | nan | 7 | 17 |
| 12 | nan | 7 | 17 |
| 13 | 13 | 10 | 17 |
| 14 | nan | 10 | 17 |
| 15 | nan | 10 | 19 |
| 16 | nan | 13 | 19 |
| 17 | 17 | 13 | nan |
| 18 | nan | 13 | nan |
| 19 | 19 | 13 | nan |

**Alternative Handling on the Start and End of the Dataset**

If for the first values you want to use the first available value instead of NA, you just have to add another `bfill` / `ffill` like this:

```
shift = 3
ser_backward = df["value"].ffill().shift(shift_b).bfill()
ser_forward = df["value"].bfill().shift(-shift_f).ffill()
df["backward"] = ser_backward
df["forward"] = ser_forward
```

Then we have a shorter loockback at the start of the dataset and a shorter lookforward at the end of the dataset and the result looks like:

|  | value | backward | forward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | nan | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 | 10 |
| 6 | nan | 3 | 10 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 | 10 |
| 8 | nan | 5 | 13 |
| 9 | nan | 5 | 13 |
| 10 | 10 | 7 | 13 |
| 11 | nan | 7 | 17 |
| 12 | nan | 7 | 17 |
| 13 | 13 | 10 | 17 |
| 14 | nan | 10 | 17 |
| 15 | nan | 10 | 19 |
| 16 | nan | 13 | 19 |
| 17 | 17 | 13 | 19 |
| 18 | nan | 13 | 19 |
| 19 | 19 | 13 | 19 |